# Is it possible that a pointer gets owned by a vector without any data copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move

If I have a C type raw pointer, is it possible to create a `std::vector` from the same type that owns the pointer's data without any data copy (only moving)? What motivates me for asking this question is the existence of `data()` member function for `std::vector` which means vector's elements are residing somewhere in the memory consecutively.

Edit: I have to add that the hope I had was also intensified by the existence of functions like `std::make_shared`.

Comment: Yes, but fear the vector being resized and invalidating your pointers. If the vector never changes size and you can guarantee this, you are safe.

Comment: Are you allocating the buffer? Then you could let the vector do that instead. Otherwise, I don't know how this could be achieved.

Comment: @user4581301 you can transfer ownership of a pre-existing array to a vector? this is news to me

Comment: Whenever you create a *vector* it owns the objects it contains. The *pointer* returned by `data()` is s non-owning raw pointer to the data owned by the *vector*.

Comment: @5gon12eder I do allocate the buffer but I am limited to using a C level API to do that.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I seem to have misread the question. And I'm not the only one, see WhiZTiM's answer.

Comment: Is the code that ran to produce that pointer modifiable? Also, what do you expect will manage the lifetime of the memory?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no. I have to de-allocate the previously allocated memory with a C level API as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this is directly possible, although you're not the first one to miss this feature. It is even more painful with `std::string` which doesn't have a non-`const` `data` member. Hopefully, this will change in C++17.

If you are allocating the buffer yourself, there is a solution, though. Just use a `std::vector` up-front. For example, assume you have the following C-style function,

```
extern void
fill_in_the_numbers(double * buffer, std::size_t count);
```

then you can do the following.

```
std::vector<double>
get_the_numbers_1st(const std::size_t n)
{
  auto numbers = std::vector<double> (n);
  fill_in_the_numbers(numbers.data(), numbers.size());
  return numbers;
}
```

Alternatively, if you're not so lucky and your C-style function insists in allocating the memory itself,

```
extern double *
allocate_the_buffer_and_fill_in_the_numbers(std::size_t n);
```

you could resort to a `std::unique_ptr`, which is sadly inferior.

```
std::unique_ptr<double[], void (*)(void *)>
get_the_numbers_2nd(const std::size_t n)
{
  return {
    allocate_the_buffer_and_fill_in_the_numbers(n),
    &std::free
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, `std::vector` is not designed to be able to assume/utilize a pre-existing array for its internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, provided that you've **created and populated** the vector before getting the pointers and that you will not

1. erase any element
2. you will not add new elements when `vec.size() == vec.capacity() - 1` ,,, doing so **will** change the address of the elements

Example

```
#include <iostream>

void fill_my_vector<std::vector<double>& vec){
    for(int i=0; i<300; i++){
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
}

void do_something(double* d, int size)
{ /* ..... */ }

int main(){
    std::vector<double> vec;
    fill_my_vector(vec);
    //You hereby promise to follow the contract conditions, then you are safe doing this

    double* ptr;
    int ptr_len = vec.size();
    ptr = &vec[0];

    //call do_something
    do_something(ptr, ptr_len);

    //ptr will be alive until this function scope exits
}
```

## EDIT

If you mean managing the data from an already created array, you can't... vector manages its own array... It cannot take ownership of an array that wasn't created by its class (vector).

Comment: If yes, now my question is how?

Comment: Ok, let me modify my answer to the 'how'

Comment: Friend, we both seem to have misread the question. @Farzad seems to have a pre-allocated pool of memory he wishes to manage with a vector, not use the vector as a pool of memory.

Comment: The EDIT part is what I meant.